# Impact of adding a MUL index on a table with 35 Million rows. The table has just 3 columns though

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have table

```
sql
show table status like 'testing_table' \G;
********************* 1. row *********************
          Name: testing_table
        Engine: InnoDB
       Version: 20
    Row_format: Compact
          Row : 35299598
 Avg_row_length: 198
 Index_length  : 1256210432
 Data_free     : 1008730112

(...)
```

I am planning to create MUL index on one of the rows in this table

**How will this have an impact on the existing table?**

**Will this improve the performance of my search?**

I am afraid with impact of creating a MUL key on the table. Also will this have impact on future inserts?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE testing_table
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `testing_table` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`myKey` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`tKey`  varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`tValue` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `myKey` (`myKey`),
CONSTRAINT `testing_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`myKey`) REFERENCES `testing_table2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=860324165 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: It is difficult to judge.  Is your search related to the existing table?  An extra index on the existing table will only have impact on future inserts into that table, not others.  Can you explain how you will create an index on a single row?

Comment: Thankyou @GerardH.Pille 

To answer your question , 
yeah my search is related to an existing table. 
Does the insert operation get impact even if the key is going to be MUL.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: We must see the "search" to judge the utility of the "index".